# How to execute an Octave file using php

Tags: php, windows-8, octave

I have an Octave file **sr.m**

```
sqrt(3^2 + 4^2)
```

I have to execute this file using **PHP** and display output in browser. The **sr.m** file is resides in `octavepgm` folder in `Desktop`.

my **php** code is

```
$cmd = "octave3.6.4 -qf C:\\Users\\deepu_000\\Desktop\\octavepgm\\sr.m";
$ex = passthru($cmd, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

This gives int 1 as output.

How can I make this working..please help me..

The expected output is 5.

Comment: @WesFoster, while using `exec` gives `array (size=0)
  empty`

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues which I explain further down but here's how you do it:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $cmd = "octave -qf --eval 'printf (\"%f\", sqrt (3^2 + 4^2));'";
php > $output = exec ($cmd);
php > var_dump ($output);
string(8) "5.000000"
```

Issue #1:

You are using `passthru()` but if you want to capture the output of octave, you should be using `exec()`. This is explained on the php manual (emphasis added):

> The passthru() function is similar to the exec() function in that it
>   executes a command. This function should be used in place of exec() or
>   system() when the output from the Unix command is binary data which
>   needs to be passed directly back to the browser.

Issue #2:

If you only want the result from Octave, you should use `printf()` otherwise you get the display of a variable, including the `ans =` part. Also, with `printf()` you can better control the format of the output.

Issue #3:

For such simple cases, use Octave's `--eval` option.

Comment: Now I am totally confused. Can you provide the code please..My requirement is to execute a octave file using php

Comment: @next2u it is php code. It's a session in a php console.